# DataFrame.apply(func) doesn't work when return is dict

Tags: python, pandas

Can I pass a function that returns a `dict` to  `DataFrame.apply`?

I am trying to create a new column in `df`, that will have `dict` objects, or `Series`. However, when I try it, I am getting unexpected results:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[9,8,7,6]})

In [3]: def df_addition(row):
   ...:         sum = row['a'] + row['b']
   ...:         return {'sum': sum}
   ...:

In [4]: df.apply(df_addition, axis=1)
Out[4]:
    a   b
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN

In [5]: df_addition(df.irow(0))
Out[5]: {'sum': 10}

In [6]: df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(df_addition(row)), axis=1)
Out[6]:
   sum
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   10
```

Comment: You don't have a column  of dicts nor a column of series: `In [26]: df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(df_addition(row)), axis=1)['sum'].dtype
Out[26]: dtype('int64')`. You have a column of `int`s.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to apply, but it shouldn't return a dict. If you want to add a sum column *your way* - do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[9,8,7,6]})

df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'], axis = 1)

df
Out[6]: 
   a  b  sum
0  1  9   10
1  2  8   10
2  3  7   10
3  4  6   10
```

An easier way would be to just do:

```
df['sum'] = df.a + df.b
```

or

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I've clarified the question now to emphasize that I specifically want a column of `dict` or `Series` objects; not just a sum.

Comment: @bornio: while you can sometimes force it as a temporary measure, `pandas` doesn't really support non-scalar entries in DataFrames.  Once you do it you'll have to do slow iterations to perform most operations.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to to store complex information in `pandas` without using dozens of columns?

Comment: @bornio pandas is meant to be used with columns. If you want something else - don't use pandas.